# About symbol position

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, symbology, graph

I have to draw in ArcGis a graph which has the end points of each segment with a circle. The circle has to be unique at the same point when two or more end points are coincident.

I’m using the font of ESRI Default Marker (Unicode 80) and the circle is not centred at the end point, but it is shifted of the ray's length along the segment. So, the result is that I have two different circles for each segment. 
If I give an offset at the position of the symbol the result is still two or more slightly different circles, but not coincident.

Is there a way to obtain an unique circle when more segments are coincident at the same end point?

Thanks for any help! I’m using ArcGis 9.3

Comment: I'm having difficulty trying to picture what you are trying to do.  Would you be able to edit your question to outline the steps you have taken so far in more detail, please?  For example, you mention graph but not whether you are using the graphing functionality of ArcMap.